# Laravel 5 Route Model Binding not working on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have an issue with Laravel 5 Route Model Binding
I am using the following Controller Method

```
public function destroy(PrimaryLocation $primaryLocation) {
    dd($primaryLocation->id);
    $primaryLocation->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('locationDeleted', true);
}
```

Where PrimaryLocation is an Eloquent Model

My RouteServiceProvider's boot function:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->model('user', 'App\User');
    $router->model('PrimaryLocation', 'App\PrimaryLocation');
}
```

And in my routes.php

```
Route::delete('deletePrimaryLocation/{PrimaryLocation}',
              ['as' => 'admin.deletePrimaryLocation', 'uses' => 'LocationsController@destroy']);
```

This setup works fine on my local Computer, but when i deploy the files to my development server, somwhere the model binding breaks;
The Location won't get deleted on executing the method.

I did some var_dumps

```
dd($primaryLocation->id);
```

on local computer this returns the correct id, but on the server it will 
just return null;

However if I do a

```
dd($primaryLocation)
```

The result is locally

```
    PrimaryLocation {#178 ▼
    #fillable: array:1 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:4 [▶]
    #original: array:4 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
  }
```

On on my Server nearly the same... but the attributes are missing:

```
        PrimaryLocation {#195 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what might be going wrong?

[UPDATE]

if I comment out

```
// $router->model('PrimaryLocation', 'App\PrimaryLocation');
```

In me ServiceProvider, the local behaviour is the same as on the server. 
Maybe there's something wrong with loading the ServiceProvider? Maybe there is some sort of cache?

Comment: The missing `attributes` is because it cannot find the record. Is the data the same in the database? i.e. same database, tables and fields? Specifically - does the record itself exist?

Comment: Is your filename correct on the server? Is it `PrimaryLocation.php` with the case sensitivity the same?

Comment: If it could not find the record, there should be a 404 error (at leas the docs state this) , if i am correct. And if the filename is not correct there should be some kind of 'hard' error... (Whoops something went wrong)

Comment: Yes - correct - but I'm just trying to rule out various issues.

Comment: Just to clarify - the issue is that the record is not been found. I dont know why it is not throwing a 404 - but the fact you get `null` for the `id` is proof of that. Plus when you `dd()` the object you can clearly see `exists: false`. So we need to confirm the record is *actually* in the database - then work it out from there.

Comment: I have a theory. Are you running different PHP versions on your production vs development? i.e. PHP 5.6 vs 5.5?

Comment: locally it's 5.5 on server it is 5.4

Comment: Can you try this model bind *instead* of your current one `$router->bind('PrimaryLocation', function($value)
{
    return App\PrimaryLocation::where('id', $value)->first();
});`

Comment: I've tried your solution... With your code it is working well on local pc, but not on server... I found out, the problem is, that the service provider does not seem to be called on server at all... Even if I totally clear the file, the result ist the same on server...It looks like it is just ignored whats in the file

Comment: What version of PHP 5.4 are you running exactly? You might need to upgrade. Can you upgrade to 5.5?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71473/discussion-between-shock-gone-wild-and-the-shift-exchange).

Comment: same problem here.. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After going through the same issue, I discovered that in production, `storage/framework/compiled.php` doesn't get rebuilt regularly like in development mode.

Basically, you are just running an old version of RoutesServiceProvider.php on your production server.

The fix is easy enough though. Just run `php artisan clear-compiled`.

It would be a good practice to add line to any deployment scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to serviceProvider::boot()

```
 $router->model('attribute', Attribute::class);
```